# How to select a link on microsoft edge using powershell?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge

I am writing a PowerShell script that requires the use of Microsoft Edge (internet explorer is blocked by admin) and needs to click on a link on a website. I was wondering what is the best approach on accomplishing this?

I have tried start using the start Microsoft edge process, but it does not allow me to interact with the site when opened.

start microsoft-edge:"https://google.com"

Comment: You can't directly interact with Edge using PowerShell. But you can use [WebDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver) to provide an API that allows you to do so. I would suggest investigating that, and after you have a script started post back with any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the suggestion given by @ kuzimoto that you will not be able to click on link using PowerShell command.

You can try to download the selenium web driver from link below.

[Download Selenium Web driver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

This is the sample code to open specific web page and click on link on the page using Selenium C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"C:\Users\panchals\Desktop\tests\login_form.html");

            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(By.Name("demo_link")).Click();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

            driver.Quit();
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

HTML page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
<script>
function abc()
{
    alert("Logged in successfully.");
}

function xyz()
{
    alert("Link clicked by selenium code....");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">


  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username :</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname"><br>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password : </b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw"><br>

    <button type="submit" name="signIn"  onclick="abc()">Login</button><br>
   <a href="" id="demo_link" name="demo_link" onclick="xyz()">Click me.......</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge:

[image]